# iOS app: Unable to log in with Google OpenID

Tags: support, ios-app, login, openid

Just got a new iPad Pro, installed the SE app and tried to log in using my Google OpenID. Getting this error every time (including deleting and reinstalling the app):

[image: SE login error]

On the first try I go through the usual username / password / Google Authenticator 2FA entry, and on subsequent attempts, Google shows the account in a list which leads me to assume all is well at their end.

Comment: The app is pretty much dead (there is no dedicated iOS developer in Stack Exchange, the only iOS developer they have has been reassigned to work on other projects), so you better just uninstall it, and use a mobile browser to visit SE.